Unable to remove SQL layer from QGIS project in plugin
I have a plugin that loads a table as a layer from the database. I want to save it in a temporary layer, because the layer accesses the database table, and the tables are rewritten each time I run the plugin, so the layers are not saved in RAM, and I want to save them. To do this, I do postgisexecuteandloadsql, then extractbyexpression and save it in memory and upload it to the project. But with this temporary layer, the SQL layer is loaded into the project, which I don't need in the end. I'm trying to remove it, but I don't manage to do it. How can this be solved? Maybe there is some other approach? The code is below
alg_params = {'DATABASE': 'postgres',
                  'GEOMETRY_FIELD': 'geom',
                  'ID_FIELD': 'id',
                  'SQL': 'SELECT * FROM table'}
    
outputs['SQLQuery'] = processing.run('qgis:postgisexecuteandloadsql', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    
extract_params = {'INPUT': outputs['SQLQuery']['OUTPUT'],
                      'EXPRESSION': 'True',
                      'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}
    
outputs['SQLQueryMemory'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression',extract_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    
load_params = {'INPUT': outputs['SQLQueryMemory']['OUTPUT'],
                   'NAME': 'Layer name'}
    
processing.run('native:loadlayer',load_params,context=context,feedback=feedback,is_child_algorithm=True)
    
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layer.name()=='SQL layer':
        QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers( [layer.id()])


Can you please explain to me what is happening on this stage processing.run('native:loadlayer',load_params,context=context,feedback=feedback,is_child_algorithm=True) ? What would you like to achieve instead ? You could try to nest an additional function i.e. onFinish inside the processing.run(...) that will delete the layer in the project after the algorithm has been completed.

@Taras I load the layer after native:extractbyexpression to the project. I want to keep it as it is, but remove 'SQL layer' layer that I have in my project after qgis:postgisexecuteandloadsql algorithm

I tried your code with my PostGIS layer, but nothing happened as you described i.e. no layer was added to the Project
